# Finding The Row Of A Pandas Dataframe When Searching With A Variable In a Column PROBLEM

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file that i imported to pandas df. Lets say it is something like this

```
#      A      B  C   D
# 0  foo    one  0   0
# 1  bar    one  1   2
# 2  foo    two  2   4
# 3  bar  three  3   6
# 4  foo    two  4   8
# 5  bar    two  5  10
# 6  foo    one  6  12
# 7  foo  three  7  14
```

When i use "foo" to search there is no problem and the statement below works as expected.

```
print(df.loc[df['A'] == 'foo'])
```

BUT when i use a "variable x" i.e. instead of "foo" to search in the Column A it doesn't return anything.

```
print(df.loc[df['A'] == variablex])
print(df.loc[df['A'] == 'variablex'])
```

How can i solve this problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Check ```list(df)``` to see if ```'variablex'``` is indeed a column name. It could be so that there are spaces, like ```' variablex'``` or ```'variablex '```

Comment: @Serge variablex would be an item here I guess, but thus likely means the item is absent or, as you said, misspelled

Comment: Checked ' variablex' or 'variablex ' but it doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: In your example, what does variablex equal?

Comment: it is a word for example "course"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ("foo","one",0,0),
    ("bar","one",1,2),
    ("foo","two",2,4),
    ("bar","three",3,6),
    ("foo","two",4,8),
    ("bar","two",5,10),
    ("foo","one",6,12),
    ("foo","three",7,14),
], columns = ["A","B","C","D"])


variablex = "foo"
print(df.loc[df["A"] == variablex])
```

Output:

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
2  foo    two  2   4
4  foo    two  4   8
6  foo    one  6  12
7  foo  three  7  14
```

I'm not sure I see what the problem is, so not sure if we've answered your question.

Comment: Yes actually i solved this problem yesterday as you said both print(df.loc[df["A"] == variablex]) and print(df.loc[df['A'] == variablex]) worked. It didn't work before for some reason maybe it was because i loaded the table from Csv and there was a mistake somewhere. Thank you.